# Swift How do I hide a view in response to an action?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view with a filter bar. One says "Shirts" & the other says "Trousers". When "Shirts" is selected, it displays a grid view of shirts. When "Trousers" is selected in the filter bar, it shows a grid view of trousers.

When I tap on an item (a shirt or a pair of trousers) it takes me to a different view (showing the product in more detail). However, the filter bar remains. I need to hide the filter bar when an item is tapped and it takes the user to a detail view.

I need to hide the marketplacefilterbar view when a product is tapped.

My ViewModel for the filter bar is:

```
enum MarketplaceFilterViewModel: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    case shirts
    case trousers
    
    var title: String {
        
        switch self {
            
        case .shirts: return "Shirts"
        case .trousers: return "Trousers"
        }
    }
}
```

Some code from the MarketplaceViewModel:

```
class MarketplaceViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
        
    @Published var search = ""
  
    // Shirt Data...
    @Published var shirts: [Shirt] = []
    @Published var filteredShirt: [Shirt] = []
    
  // Trouser Data...
    @Published var trousers: [Trouser] = []
    @Published var filteredTrouser: [Trouser] = []
    
}
```

Code for the marketplace view is:

```
   ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        
            VStack(spacing: 10){
          
                marketplaceFilterBar
                
                if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .raise {
                    MarketplaceShirtView()
                }
                
                if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .save {
                    MarketplaceTrouserView()
                }
            }
        }

   var marketplaceFilterBar: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack(spacing: 15){

                Image("Logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 60.0, height: 60.0)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 45, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            .padding([.horizontal,.top])
            
            HStack {
            ForEach(MarketplaceFilterViewModel.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(selectedMarketplaceFilter == item ? .semibold: .regular)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedMarketplaceFilter == item ? .black: .gray)
                    
                    if selectedMarketplaceFilter == item {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("LightBlue"))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "filter", in: animation)
                        
                    } else {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.clear))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        self.selectedMarketplaceFilter  = item
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
        .overlay(Divider().offset(x: 0, y: 16))
        }
    }
```

Code for the Shirt Detail View:

```
struct ShirtDetailView: View {

    @Binding var shirtData : Shirt!
    @Binding var showDetailShirt: Bool
    
    @Namespace var animation: Namespace.ID
    
    // Shared Data Model...
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    
    @EnvironmentObject var marketplaceData: MarketplaceViewModel
    


ScrollView {
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {

                                        withAnimation(.easeOut){showDetailShirt.toggle()}

                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                            .background(Color.white,in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                                    }
                
 
                    Text(shirtData.shirt_name)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
  
            }         
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                    
                WebImage(url: URL(string: shirtData.shirt_image))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
            
                Text("Details")
                    .opacity(0.7)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.bottom)
               
                  
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                
                Text(shirtData.shirt_details)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding()
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the Trouser Detail View:

```
struct TrouserDetailView: View {

    @Binding var trouserData : Trouser!
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool
    
    @Namespace var animation: Namespace.ID
    
    // Shared Data Model...
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    
    @EnvironmentObject var marketplaceData: MarketplaceViewModel
    


ScrollView {
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {

                                        withAnimation(.easeOut){showDetailTrouser.toggle()}

                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                            .background(Color.white,in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                                    }
                
 
                    Text(trouserData.trouser_name)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
  
            }         
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                    
                WebImage(url: URL(string: trouserData.trouser_image))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
            
                Text("Details")
                    .opacity(0.7)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.bottom)
               
                  
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                
                Text(trouserData.trouser_details)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding()
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the SharedDataModel:

```
class SharedDataModel: ObservableObject {

  // Detail Shirt Data...
    @Published var detailShirt : Shirt?
    @Published var showDetailShirt : Bool = false 
    
    // matched Geoemtry Effect from Search page...
    @Published var fromSearchPage: Bool = false
    
}
```

The updated code for marketplace:

```
    @Binding var charityData : Charity!
    @Binding var showDetailCharity: Bool
    
    @Binding var businessData : Business!
    @Binding var showDetailBusiness: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                
                
                if !showDetailCharity && !showDetailBusiness {
                //MARK: This is the filter bar - the view for this is further down the page
                marketplaceFilterBar
                    
                }
                
                if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .raise {
                    MarketplaceRaiseView()
                }
                
                if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .save {
                    MarketplaceSaveView()
                }
            }
```

The code for TabView:

```
 @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    
    @StateObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel = SharedDataModel()
    

    // Animation Namespace...
    @Namespace var animation
    
    // Hiding Tab Bar...
    init(){
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            // Tab View...
            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) {
                
                
                Marketplace(animation: _animation)
                    .environmentObject(sharedData)
                    .tag(Tab.Market)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                Home()
                    .environmentObject(sharedData)
                    .tag(Tab.Home)
                    .setUpTab()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have `showDetailShirt` and `showDetailTrouser`, you can use them to hide the `marketplacefilterbar` like so:

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
   VStack(spacing: 10){
      if !showDetailShirt && !showDetailTrouser {
         marketplaceFilterBar
      }
                
      if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .raise {
         MarketplaceShirtView()
      }
                
      if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .save {
         MarketplaceTrouserView()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful however when I add this code, I get errors in my TabView. For the Marketplace Tab I get the errors: Missing arguments for parameters 'shirtData', 'showDetailShirt', 'trouserData', 'showDetailTrouser' in call.

Comment: Could you share the code of your TabView and how you are adding the above code?